# Injecting Javascript when a Modal is loaded

Tags: jquery, scroll, modal-dialog, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a little problem, i am trying to achive what is happening in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yXRSz/ basicly it enables a button when the T&C's have been read.

The problem that i am having is that i want this to happen in a AjaxControlToolkit Modal window. The javascript is not running the scroll function when the modal appears and scroll bar is moved. The scroll bar is the overflow on a div

I expect this is becase the modal is hidden when the JS is loaded, i have tried to add the onload and oninit methods and inject the script to the page with no luck, anyone have any idea on how i inject once then modal has loaded?

Code Below

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAcceptTerms" runat="server">
                        <div id="divTerms" class="modal modal_styled_dark" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h3 id="H1">Terms & Conditions</h3>
                                <p>
                                    You have chosen to enter score values, in order for us to proceed with the values you have entered you must accept
                                    that we hold no responsibility for the values that you have entered. If you decline this we will only display the factual information.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body" id="divTermsScrollArea" runat="server">
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                                <p>Terms and conditions are entered here</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="button-wrapper submit-button-wrapper clearfix">
                                    <div class="button-input-wrapper submit-button-input-wrapper" style="float: left;">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnDeclineTerms" runat="server" Text="I Decline Terms" CssClass="ka-form-submit"
                                            CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnDeclineTerms_Click" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="button-input-wrapper submit-button-input-wrapper" style="float: right;">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnAcceptTerms" runat="server" Text="I Accept Terms" CssClass="ka-form-submit"
                                            OnClick="btnAcceptTerms_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="true" Enabled="false" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divScrollScript" runat="server"></div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeTerms" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnHideMe2"
                        PopupControlID="pnlAcceptTerms" DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modal-backdrop" OnLoad="mpeTerms_Load" OnInit="mpeTerms_Init">
                    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

And code behind i have

```
            string script = "";
        script += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n";
        script += "     alert('#" + divTermsScrollArea.ClientID + "');\r\n";
        script += "     jQuery('#" + divTermsScrollArea.ClientID + "').scroll(function () {\r\n";
        script += "         alert(jQuery(this).scrollTop());\r\n";
        script += "         if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() == jQuery(this)[0].scrollHeight - (jQuery(this).height() + 30)) {\r\n";
        script += "             jQuery('#" + btnAcceptTerms.ClientID + "').removeAttr('disabled');\r\n";
        script += "         }\r\n";
        script += "     });\r\n";
        script += "</script>\r\n";

        divScrollScript.InnerHtml = script;
```

+30 is becasue of the padding on the div

Cheers
Joe.

Comment: I have moved the script to the page, when the page does the init load, i get a nice alert telling me the scroll height, but when the modal takes over and hides the div, it appears to lose the scroll function added to it. Does anyone have any clue as how to override the show function on the modal, maybe i can inject the script there when the modal is actually showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right this took me some time to work out, but i have in fact managed to add a show event to the modal popup extended

Just in case anyone else runs into the same issue my new code is below

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            // add event handler to modal show event
            // enable accept button when scroll to bottom of terms
            function pageLoad() {
                $find('<%= mpeTerms.ClientID %>').add_shown(function () {
                    jQuery('#<%= divTermsScrollArea.ClientID %>').scroll(function () {
                        //console.log(jQuery(this).scrollTop().toString() + ' : ' + (jQuery(this)[0].scrollHeight - (jQuery(this).height() + 30)).toString());
                        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() == (jQuery(this)[0].scrollHeight - (jQuery(this).height() + 30))) {
                            jQuery('#<%= btnAcceptTerms.ClientID %>').removeAttr('disabled');
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
```

The $find(modal popup exender name).add_shown( function () {

adds a function to the modal popups show event, enables you to run script inside there, i got the code for this from http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/archive/2010/04/15/add-shown-amp-add-hiding-modalpopupextender-events.aspx

the reason my original code was not working is because the modal on the page load is shown, but when the popup extender loads it hides it, thus rendering the js useless. So by adding the scroll function when the modal is shown the js is active :)

Cheers
Joe.

Answer (score 1):

```
string script = "";
script += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n";
script += "   jQuery(function() {\r\n";
script += "     jQuery(document).on('scroll', '#" + divTermsScrollArea.ClientID + "', function () {\r\n";
script += "         if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() == jQuery(this)[0].scrollHeight - (jQuery(this).height() + 30)) {\r\n";
script += "             jQuery('#" + btnAcceptTerms.ClientID + "').prop('disabled', false);\r\n";
script += "         }\r\n";
script += "     });\r\n";
script += "   });\r\n";
script += "</script>\r\n";​
```

Comment: Good effort and i can see what you have done there, but no cigar :( for some unknown reason its not registering the scroll

Comment: @jderonde - now the scroll event is registered on the document level, so any scroll will fire the event, and then it's filtered based on selector, so only option for it not working that you are targeting the wrong element or that the IF condition is'nt working. The latter is easy to test by placing a console log inside the scroll function to see if it fires or not.

Comment: Yeah, i have added a log to the scroll functuion but its not firing, its deffinatily on the correct div - check that in developer tools. I think it has something to do with modal where it hides it then shows it again.